# course vs module vs lecture vs seminar

Tags: computer-science, united-states, united-kingdom, terminology

My question concerns terminology in computer-science MSc/BSc education in universities. Let us consider the following terms:

- course
- module
- lecture
- seminar

in the US and the UK.

Which terms denote one-off events, which events last a term, and which events denote a whole BSc/MSc program? (Yes, I've read [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_(education)), but it seems controversial.)

Comment: A course consists of several modules which are delivered as a series of lectures. Seminars are independent, one-off events. A course might last one or more terms. A BSc/MSc program comprises many courses. (I suspect that course, module and unit are sometimes used interchangeably.)

Comment: @user2768 Unclear. In which of the two countries?

Comment: Both. But, usage between institutes may vary.

Comment: @user2768: Please post as an answer so people can vote and comment in a more orderly manner.

Comment: @user2768 The field is computer science, if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

### US usage

A course is generally the main unit of instruction. You will register for a course that lasts a term--which could be a semester or a quarter depending on the university.

There could also be a year-long course but it would actually be two or three courses that you would have to register for each term.

It's also possible to hear the term "course of study" which is the set of courses that you need to take to fulfill requirements for a degree.

The term module is not very common in the US, but it would be a themed subset of a course. I've seen it used in professional development courses.

A lecture is one meeting of a course.

A seminar could be a one-off lecture or meeting but a seminar course or a course using a seminar format would be designed for a small group, likely under 20, with more discussion rather than lecture or every student presenting on various topics over the term.

### UK usage

Course is used for the entire set of topics to be covered for the degree, so corresponding to course of study in the US.

A module is a themed subset of the course, what would be called a course in the US.

A lecture has the same meaning as does a seminar.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the terms you've listed generally have multiple meanings. However, the most common usage of the terms are as follows:

- Lecture or seminar: Can refer to an individual meeting of a class, or an individual talk. Can also refer to a set of meetings, as in a lecture or seminar series. It can also refer to a mode of instruction, such as in a lecture or seminar course.
- Course: Primarily the main form of instruction, usually including some combination of lectures, laboratories, seminars, recitation or discussion sections, and so on, usually focused on one theme, that may or may not be part of the "major" a student is concentrating on. (An important exception in the US is at MIT, where "course" refers to a program, and "subject" refers to what is normally called a course. Also, Harvard refers to a one-semester course as a "half-course.")
- Module: Generally a subset of a course.

As for the UK, I will defer to others, as I am not as familiar with the usage there.

Answer (score -1):

If I guess correctly, I would think there is a desire for understanding the hierarchy of a education learning? (I could be wrong?)

My take on the hierarchy:

Curriculum -> Course(s) -> Lecture(s) -> Module(s)

A curriculum is a list of courses, while a course can contain one or more lectures.
Each lecture can have one or more modules. A module can be further broken down to contain content, assignment(s), quiz, etc.

Comment: This is close to US usage (not UK). But a "module" might require several "lectures" to cover. A "module" on limits and another on derivatives, for example, in a first calculus "course".